# canot clear cach by code in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, caching

I have a page that needs to be open for awhile.
After a couple of hours, the memory gets full and cause a memory leak.
To solve that issue after an hour I refresh the browser:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

In chrome, it works fine but in explorer, it doesn't work.
I tried:

- 1)

`$window.location.reload(true);`

- 2)

  in index.html I added:
  to the meta tag

  http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
     http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
      http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>"
- 3

  $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
          if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
              $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
          }
          // disable IE ajax request caching
          $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

How can I solve that issue also in IE, How to clear cache\reload page from code so that I will not get a memory leak?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to try to fix the leaking code instead of treating the symptons ..?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">` to refresh every 30 seconds maybe?

Comment: The leaking is caused due to alot of XHR events and UI component that I used with.. nohing that releated to the code

Comment: First, location.reload for sure wipes all Js objects. Second, your index.html caching settings make no sense at all. All these seems strange... do you have kind of ActiveX components?